# Adding/removing items from Listview programatically?

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to create an app for my Samsung Gear S3 that takes data from an API, dynamically creates a Listview, and propagates it using the data returned via the API. I've got as far as putting the items in the list, but when the page is hidden I want to remove everything from the list. Since I'm doing it programmatically in the first place, there's no easy way such as removing all of the elements using a querySelector and refreshing the Listview.

That said, much how I'm using `.addItem` - is there a `.removeItem` or equivalent that isn't documented?

At the moment, I'm listening to the `pagebeforehide` event and calling `.destroy()` on the created Listview - which works in the sense that the `_items` property is cleared but the Listview is still displaying all of the items from before...

The code I have at the moment can be seen below.

```js
(function() {
    var page = document.getElementById('search.results'),
        listView;
    var elems = [ ];
    
    page.addEventListener("pagebeforeshow", function() {
        if(sessionStorage.length && sessionStorage.getItem("currentResults")) {
            var currentResults = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("currentResults"));
            var elem = document.getElementById("results-list");
            listView = tau.widget.Listview(elem, { dataLength: currentResults.length, bufferSize: 10 });
            listView.setListItemUpdater(function(listElement, newIndex) {
                var data = currentResults[newIndex];
                listElement.innerHTML = data.Description;
                listElement.id = data.EAN;
            });
        }
        
        $("li").click(function(e) {
            var li = $(e.target);
            if(li.attr("id")) {
                var EAN = li.attr("id");
                tau.changePage("product.html", { name: li.innerHTML, ean: EAN });
            }
        });
    });
    
    page.addEventListener("pagebeforehide", function() {
        console.log("page before hide");
        if(sessionStorage.length && sessionStorage.getItem("currentResults")) {
            console.log(sessionStorage);
            sessionStorage.removeItem("currentResults");
            console.log(sessionStorage);
        }
        listView.destroy();
        console.log(listView);
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This list does not actually have an API for removing items or binding to data.
I see you have solved this problem practically by yourself.

I think it is enough to clear the base element of the list now, eg. `listView.element.innerHTML = ""` or `document.getElementById("results-list").innerHTML = ""`.

I think you can also create issue on https://github.com/Samsung/TAU/issues
because the `.destroy()` method should remove items which was not attached to widget before widget build.

Comment: I searched the issues page and it looks like someone already brought up the issue of .destroy() re-appending the removed elements, and from the code in the pull request it looks as if this has been fixed. As for removing the elements, I'll try using .innerHTML and setting it to blank and see if that works better.

Comment: Nevermind... there was no issue with the Listview. It was me being an idiot and not clearing the array all the results are stored into before sending the data... Thank you for the help nonetheless! @Tomasz